# Cant figure out how to make python accept any time within specific format

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
if p_message == "00:00":
    return "TIME HAS BEEN SUBMITTED"
```

I am trying to make a discord bot I programed with python to respond to any time written like this "11:11" as an example.
Is there anyway to add variables to what it searches for so 03:11 or 10:23 will get the same response?
I already have different commands set up that work fine, I just need this one to work without interfering, preferably by replacing the 0's with something that will accept any number, but not letter.

I have managed to get the code to work because of the answers, so thanks. (I realize people ask for what has been tried, sorry but I already deleted all the old code, but most of it was centered around the import random function, which I now realize was not the way to go)

Comment: “*I have tried using a bunch of different solutions but nothing has worked.*” Can you share these attempts as [mre]s in accordance with our guidance on [ask]? It would be very helpful to understand slightly more context and the code you’ve written so far to ensure we don’t duplicate your efforts and can potentially show where you’ve gone wrong previously. Have you tried using regular expressions? This type of problem is exactly in the wheelhouse of what they’re typically used for.

Comment: As esqew mentioned in their comment you are expected to show us the solution(s) you have tried. Don't just tell us you "tried using a bunch of different solutions but nothing has worked." We know everything you tried didn't work. Otherwise you wouldn't have opened a question asking for help. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) are your friend. Assuming your format is "two digits, then a colon, then two more digits", you can match that as follows.

```
import re

DIGITS = r'^\d{2}:\d{2}$'

my_match = re.match(DIGITS, message)
```

`re.match` returns a [`Match` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects) on success (which is truthy), or `None` on failure (which is falsy), so it can be used in an `if` statement to get the result you want. You can also read up on capture groups to extract the hours and minutes components, if needed for your use case. I encourage you to read the `re` module documentation to learn more about regular expressions, as the syntax can be very different if you're not accustomed to it.

Comment: Keep in mind that this regex also matches invalid times, such as 99:99 so you'll need to handle those cases if necessary

Comment: The following pattern should be more complete for 12 hr time, assuming : as a separator.  `r'^((0?[0-9])|(1[0-2])):[0-5][0-9]$')`.  I would probably write a second separate pattern for 24 hour time which would be similar.